# Correct combining characters positions with Harfbuzz

Tags: text-rendering, harfbuzz

I am trying to render text with Harfbuzz and a signed distance field atlas.

The code is basically this:

```cpp
void drawText(const std::wstring &str, Vec2 pos)
{
    // Init harfbuzz
    hb_buffer_t *hbBuf = hb_buffer_create();
    hb_buffer_set_direction(hbBuf, HB_DIRECTION_LTR);
    hb_buffer_set_script(hbBuf, HB_SCRIPT_LATIN);
    hb_buffer_set_language(hbBuf, hb_language_from_string("en", 2));

    // Process string
    hb_buffer_add_utf32(hbBuf, reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(str.c_str()), -1, 0, -1);
    hb_shape(font.hb, hbBuf, nullptr, 0);

    // Display string
    unsigned int nbGlyphs;
    hb_glyph_info_t *glyphInfos = hb_buffer_get_glyph_infos(hbBuf, &nbGlyphs);
    hb_glyph_position_t *glyphPos = hb_buffer_get_glyph_positions(hbBuf, &nbGlyphs);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nbGlyphs; i++)
    {
        Vec2 drawPos = pos + Vec2(glyphPos[i].x_offset, glyphPos[i].y_offset) / 64.f;
        drawGlyph(glyphInfos[i].codepoint, drawPos);
        pos.x += glyphPos[i].x_advance / 64.f;
        pos.y += glyphPos[i].y_advance / 64.f;
    }
}
```

The text looks correctly shaped for an English phrase, but when I test it with diacritics, they look misplaced.
I am testing it with `aâa aâ̈a bb̂b bb̂̈b bb̧b bb͜b bb︠︡b`. The Unicode string does not contain precombined characters. `Harfbuzz` uses the precombined character `â`, which makes this one look good. Most other diacritics are off.

[Text with diacritics on the left of where they should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64hzE.png)

When I multiply `x_offset` by `0.5`, the combining characters are better placed. The accents and the cedilla are at the right x position. The accents do not stack and are too low on the `b`. The arc under `BBB` (U+035C) should join the two last letters instead of being centered on the 2nd `b`.

I also tried with U+FE20 and U+FE21 on the previous group of `b`. In my tests, U+FE21 is on the 2nd `b`, but it looks like it should be on the 3rd.

[Test with `glyphPos[i].x_offset * 0.5f`, better but still wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkXmv.png)

I tried with several fonts, but of those fonts, only NotoSansDisplay-Regular.ttf had combining characters. I did not manage to make a program display that string as expected on my Debian system (testing, with HarfBuzz 2.6.4-1).

With Windows, I got better results. Here is what I expect: the accents are stacked, the combining double breve below it at the right place, the cedilla is off.

[Text rendering closer to what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzcXa.png)

Am I doing something wrong with HarfBuzz, or I am testing to niche cases that HarfBuzz does support yet?

**EDIT:**

The actual problem was not described above.
I loaded a font with FreeType `FT_New_Face` then created a `hb_font_t` with hb_ft_font_create.
For every string drawn, I called `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes` but kept that `hb_font_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try shaping the same text and font with hb-view / hb-shape.  That would help you narrow down where the problem is.  I'm making a wild guess that the problem is in how / whether you are accounting for glyph origin in your atlas.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `hb_font_t` with `hb_ft_font_create` every time the font size i changed with `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes`.